# Phone availability

Tags: ubuntu-touch

What's the deal with the phones? I didn't see the entire cycle but it seems like the Meizu Pro 5 was available for about 5 weeks. The others have never been available in that time. Is there a schedule? a plan? Thank you.

Comment: I have been looking at getting one myself, but as yet there is no sign of it becoming available again. I really hope that it comes up soon as I really want one. I have asked a few times on here and there is no definate date given. I carry on looking in the hope that I can buy it soon though.

Answer (score 2):

The Pro 5 won't be available again. Some developers have had success flashing Ubuntu on Pro 5's which shipped with Android. However that process isn't straightforward, and doesn't support the Ubuntu project through device sales.

Other devices are on the short term road-map, and should be available to buy soon. Unfortunately Canonical have little control over the availability of devices, that's down to the partner, in this case Meizu. I'd recommend contacting the manufacturer to let them know you're interested in Ubuntu devices :).

Comment: Put my name down too, for people that are interested in buying one.